# different table with same with

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am dynamically generating tables one after another using asp.net c#.I have different section in a table

td.section{width:200px;}

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="section">Sec 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>s</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="section">Sec 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3" class='section'>Sec 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want each sections must be same with but I am unable to do this.Can you guide me how can I do this.

Comment: Are the 'talbe's supposed to be 'table's?  and is the 'with' supposed to be 'width'?  Or is that the way you actually have it coded out?

Comment: i add to @Charmless and Ryan that you should write </table> and not </talbe>. also i suggest setting the table width in the table's tag using styles:  <table style="width:200px;">

Comment: I know but my width is not matching

Answer (score 1):

I added the width attribute at the top within a style tag and I think I got what you're aiming for.  Note that width is spelled with a "d" and you are also missing a "<" on your second  tag.

Finished product:

```
<style>
td.section{width:200px;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' class='section'>Sec 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>s</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td class='section'>Sec 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>

</tr>
</table>

<tr>
<td colspan='3' class='section'>Sec 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>

</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is just for demo purpose

Comment: Okay. I think putting the width tag in the style section will do what you need. I have a table with equal widths when I open the code I put in my answer.

Comment: actually i am creating a report.Its for different they are not applicable for all tables

Comment: Then I would suggest you make different tag styles for different tables, as required.  I.E:
<style>
td_table1.section{width:200px;}
td_table2.section{width:50px;}
td_table3.section{width:400px;}
</style>

With more descriptive names as per their purpose, of course.  That will allow you to customize your style for each table.  You might pursue a full style sheet if you need more customization, though. W3Schools has great tutorials on CSS.